# installing aptitude package manager on debian core.with the following code It is saying that package 'aptitude' has no installation candidate.

Tags: linux, package-management, aptitude

how can i install aptitude on debian 8.7.  I mean the debian core since the installation have not given me any desktop options. i used the netinstall but it did not give me any desktop option so now am tryiing to build them up.Any help is highly appreciated.